# What do you call the long straight piece of metal set on the ground at bus stops?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

What do you call the long straight pieces of metal, set into the ground, that you find at bus stops (at least in Canada)? People stand next to the post when waiting for the bus.

They look like this:

[image]

Do you call it a *bus stop post*?

Comment: In what country is this found?

Comment: @TinfoilHat Canada. It is found in the transit system in Toronto.

Comment: Though [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bus-stop) defines **bus stop** as 'a place, usually with a pole with a sign, where a bus stops to allow passengers to get on and off', 'bus stop' is also used for the pole itself (for instance in diecast model catalogues).

Comment: This question is exceptionally localised and unlikely to be of use to other readers. It is also likely to be answered by minimal research.

Comment: Title contradicts question: former says "on the ground", latter "in the ground", which are different places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a **pole** ... [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pole) has

> **pole**
> a long, thin stick of wood or metal, often used standing straight up in the ground to support things

... or a **post**. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/post)

> **post**
> a vertical stick or pole stuck into the ground, usually to support something or show a position

Answer (score 2):

I would ignore the long straight piece of metal and focus on the thing it supports:  I would call it a *bus stop sign.*  This has the advantage of applying when the sign is affixed to a building or to a shelter.